# SHA256 has table cli and openssl library

Tags: c, openssl, sha256

I'm trying to understand how the openssl library works compared to the CLI, and can't manage to find how to use SHA256 in both of those to get the same answer.

im using **OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013**

my CLI command is

```
echo a | openssl sha256
```

output

(stdin)= 87428fc522803d31065e7bce3cf03fe47596631e5e07bbd7a0fde60c4cf25c7

C program

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    unsigned char       msg[ 100 ];
    long unsigned int   msg_len;
    unsigned char       md[ SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH ];      // SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH = 32

    msg_len = 100;
    memset( msg, 0, msg_len );
    msg[ 0 ] = 'a';
    msg[ 1 ] = '\0';

    if ( ! simpleSHA256( msg, msg_len, md ) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    hex_print( md );          // for 0<=i<=32 do printf( "%02x", md[ i ] );
}
```

where

```
bool simpleSHA256( void *input, unsigned long length, unsigned char *md ) {
    SHA256_CTX    context;
    if ( ! SHA256_Init( &context ) )
        return false;
    if ( ! SHA256_Update( &context, (unsigned char*)input, length ) )
        return false;
    if ( ! SHA256_Final( md, &context ) ) 
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

with output:

```
653504743d03afc72051d85fce9bcb8afd05d7911e5c9fe91265fa36d7d98b0
```

what am I doing wrong? cause both of those are suppose to give back the same output

Comment: One thing is certainly that `echo a` will print `a`, `\n`. The newline can be suppressed by `echo -n a`. But the result still differs, so this isn't the whole answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `echo a` it prints the letter *and* a newline. So the string you use in the C program should be `"a\n"`.

Also, you do the checksum of *all* of the array, not only the two letters used in the command line example. Use the proper length instead.

Comment: OP is also processing 100 characters in their example.

Comment: @ItaySela: The whole point of a cryptographically secure hash is that a *minute* change in input will give a *completely* different output. And since a hash is supposed to work on binary data as well, zero bytes *do* matter. ;-)